# RavenDB - How to replicate an index, not a document collection, on SQL Replication

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm using RavenDB 3.0 SQL Replication, and it works fine for me on document collections.
But now I need to replicate an index (which includes Reduce).

In documentation of older version (2.0) I saw that Index Replication was available.

How can I use it in version 3.0, from the Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the index replication bundle and compile that on 3.0

Comment: The studio's SQL Replication will support it when using an index name in the Source Document Collection?

Comment: No, it isn't supported. Only collections are supported.